# Transposing from range to end of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code, that has to transpose the data. Problem is, that I don't know how to make it dynamic, so it can transpose more than till column "O". But if there is 300 rows of data, it should be able to transpose that data down the columns.

```
Sub TransposeData()
    Range("A2:O15").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A2:O8"))
End Sub
```

I have just a test data set here, but when i add more than 15 rows of data, it cant transpose it beyond the column "O".

Data set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Range("A2:O15").Value = Application.Transpose(Range("A2:O8"))
```

However that won't work because the destination range is of different size from the original. Better, assign the `Value` of A2:O15 to an array and then

```
Range("A2").Resize(Ubound(Arr,2), Ubound(Arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
```

You can make A2:O15 dynamic with code like this.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Arr as Variant

Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(XlUp).Offset(0,15))
Arr = Rng.Value
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but i have a lot of data after row 17, is there a way to remove them while transposing?

Comment: I just added a new sub, but i wanted if it could be within the transpose sub
    Worksheets("Ark1").Rows(17 & ":" & Worksheets("Ark1").Rows.Count).Delete

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this for more dinamically:

```
Sub TransposeMe()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range("A2:O15")
    Dim destRange As Range
    Set destRange = Range("A2")
    Set destRange = destRange.Resize(myRange.Columns.Count, myRange.Rows.Count)
    destRange.Value = Excel.Application.Transpose(myRange)
End Sub
```